# Can we use the modal verb 'Can' to suggest a future action?

Tags: modal-verbs

For example-
You can Spend your vacation in Dubai.
You could Spend your vacation in Dubai.
Are there any difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can spend your vacation in Dubai
>
> You may spend your vacation in Dubai
>
> You will spend your vacation in Dubai
>
> You shall spend your vaction in Dubai

all refer to future action but emphasize different attitudes with respect to that future action.

The "can" variant emphasizes your expected physical capacity to perform that action without reference to its probability. The "may" variant emphasizes that you are free to perform the action without any serious expectation of adverse consequence or that the speaker is unwilling to predict whether performance is probable or not. The "will" variant emphasizes the speaker's confidence in future performance. The "shall" variant emphasizes an expectaion of adverse consequences for failure to perform in the future. Modals are powerful but subtle.

Casual writing may not distinguish between "could" and "can." But in the context of your question, a careful user of English would use them in different situations. The "could" or "might" variants with respect to a future event would usually be used to indicate possibility subject to certain conditions precedent.

> You can vacation in Dubai

seems to show no expectation that conditions precedent must first be met. In contrast

You could vacation in Dubai if the jury finds you innocent

qualifies capacity by a specified constraint.